# How to provide username and password when using "net user /domain"

Tags: networking, cmd.exe

Like the title said, I wanted to use `net user /domain` to get a list of users on my local domain. The problem is, it returns me 
"Access is denied" error.

I know it requires logging on to the domain, and I do know the username and password. How should I pass my credentials along with the `net user /domain` command?

`/user:username` did not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a more elegant way, but this should work:

```
runas /user:DOMAIN\USERNAME "net user /domain"
```

You'll be prompted for your password and then it should run.

By the way, you might also be interested in the Powershell cmdlet `Get-ADUser`.